# Rails Models: Can one belong and yet have many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, relational-database, rails-models

Say I have two tables in a database: a user and and an article. A user creates the article, but the article can also be saved to a different user's list (these are just examples, don't ask me why they'd do that). How would this relationship be represented in a database since a set has a one-to-one created with relationship with a user, but at the same time it could also have many users if they added it to their items? Is something like the following possible (I am writing this in Rails)?

```
class User

  #something

end

class Article

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :users

end
```

Or would you need to add an additional list Table?

```
class User

  has_many :lists
  has_many :articles, through: :lists

end

class Article

  has_many :lists
  has_many :users, through: :lists

end

class List

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is indeed how you would do it. You could, in addition, have a separate `belongs_to :user` relationship from `Article` to `User` to indicate authorship, as you had in the first approach.